# Splitting all output directories in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

Gradle 4.0 came out yesterday and I updated my project for it.

Now I am getting the following warning:

> Gradle now uses separate output directories for each JVM language, but
>   this build assumes a single directory for all classes from a source
>   set. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed
>   in Gradle 5.0

I would like to use separate output directories for each language. What do I need to change to make that happen?

---

Things I tried:

- `gradle clean` followed by `gradle build`
- deleting the build directory then running `gradle build`.
- deleting the gradle and build directory then running `gradle`

---

Related GitHub [issue](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/865)

---

Gradle Plugins:

- java
- eclipse
- idea
- org.springframework.boot

Comment: Which Gradle plugins are you using?

Comment: java, eclipse, idea, org.springframework.boot

Comment: Have you tried asking at the Spring Boot project?

Comment: Nope. However I am pretty sure it is them...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Gradle 4.0 introduces multiple `sourceSet`s per JVM language in order to enable remote build caching. With the `java` plugin your `build/classes/main` should become `build/classes/java/main` and `build/classes/test` should become `build/classes/java/test`, etc.

The warning you're seeing is defined in [DefaultSourceSets.java](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/bb0ed850aa4061931a62133091d66c56551cf5e0/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/DefaultSourceSetOutput.java#L79)

Therefore, if any plugin within your project or your `build.gradle` calls `DefaultSourceSetOutput.getClassesDir()` (or access `classesDir`) you get this warning.

### Solution 1

Use

```
sourceSets.main.output.classesDir = new File(buildDir, "classes/main")
```

which corresponds to:

```
@Override
public boolean isLegacyLayout() {
    return classesDir!=null;
}

@Override
public void setClassesDir(File classesDir) {
    setClassesDir((Object)classesDir);
}

@Override
public void setClassesDir(Object classesDir) {
    this.classesDir = classesDir;
    this.classesDirs.setFrom(classesDir);
}
```

Note that [SourceSetOutput.java](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/SourceSetOutput.html#getClassesDir()) marks `getClassesDir()` as deprecated.

So until all plugins in your project get support for Gradle 4.0 you should stick to the workaround and ignore the deprecation warnings.

Another issue is test files. **If you don't want to have the new layout** (`build/classes/main` and `build/classes/java/test`) you should adjust test path too:

```
sourceSets.main.output.classesDir = new File(buildDir, "classes/main")
sourceSets.test.output.classesDir = new File(buildDir, "classes/test")
```

**UPDATE** 
Users of IDEA may notice that IDE starts using separate `out` directories for build if Gradle 4.x is detected. That makes impossible **hot app reloading** if you run app outside of IDEA. To fix that add and reimport:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    // Due to Gradle 4.x changes (separate output directories per JVM language)
    // Idea developers refuse to reuse Gradle classpath and use own 'out/' directory.
    // Revert to old behavior to allow Spring Devtool to work with using fast Idea compiler.
    // https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175172
    // Alternatively use native Gradle builds or bootRun.addResources = true
    // To use this feature push Ctrl+Shift+F9 to recompile!
    // Be aware that Idea put resources into classes/ directory!!
    idea.module.inheritOutputDirs = false
    idea.module.outputDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
    idea.module.testOutputDir = sourceSets.test.output.classesDir
}
```

Please note that IDEA puts resources into the same directory as `.class` files so your Gradle classpath could be corrupted. Just do `gradle clean` for modules on which you use IDEA built-in build commands (Ctrl+Shift+F10, etc).

Comment: We were already using setClassesDir for other reasons, but we get the warning anyway. I actually tried removing our call to it thinking that maybe it was the reason for the warning, lol.

Comment: @Trejkaz The reason is that `setClassesDir` now produces exactly the same warning: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/c684c202534c4138b51033b52d871939b8d38d72/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/DefaultSourceSetOutput.java#L95

Comment: Maybe I meant `setClassesDirs` then, given the context. But our current build doesn't have either of the calls anymore, and I still see the same warning. :)   (I should note, what I think is actually going on for us, is that some _plugin_ is calling one of the deprecated methods...)

Comment: Where's your source stating that this is the officially recommended solution?

Comment: @Alex It is officially **not recommended** / **deprecated** way and should be avoided at any cost, unless you understand what are you doing )) Modern Idea should understand multi-lang Gradle builds, I need to verify this and throw old workaround.

Answer (score 5):

This is due to the change introduced in Gradle 4.0: it now uses separate output directories if there are multiple language sources.

To return to the old behaviour and get rid of the warning, insert this into your build.gradle:

`// Change the output directory for the main source set back to the old path
sourceSets.main.output.classesDir = new File(buildDir, "classes/main")`

Reference: https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/release-notes.html#multiple-class-directories-for-a-single-source-set

Comment: By the way, forgot to mention, but probably those warnings would go away when plugins catch up with the changes introduced in Gradle 4.0 and add the new build directories to their definitions. ie: for the java plugin, from ```src/main/java` -> build/classes/main``` to ```src/main/java` -> build/classes/java/main```

Answer (score 0):

My case was a bit specific because output classes directories were used to construct classpath entry for command-line execution. But perhaps this will help someone.

I decided to concatenate all output directories. The change I made was form

```
sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
```

to

```
ext {
    classpathSeparator = System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')?";":":"
}
...
sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs.join(classpathSeparator)
```

Answer (score -1):

For example, if you mix Java, Kotlin and Groovy project structure should be like the following:

```
root/
    src/
       main/
            java/
            kotlin/
            groovy/
       test/
            java/
            kotlin/
            groovy/
```

In you *build.gradle* you have to specify plugins that are required for specific language.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
```

Comment: You only explain what separate output directories are, not how it can be accomplished. This does still not explain how to set the output directories in the Gradle build file or how to get rid of the warning.

Comment: I also doubt that output directories should be sub directories of the source directory (src).

Comment: I have included: `apply plugin: 'java'` and as @mantono has said it has not disabled the warning.