# Gradle v4 to Gradle v5 Update - separate output directories for each JVM language

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I'm looking to update Gradle from v4 to v5 but I'm getting the below warning on v4:

> Gradle now uses separate output directories for each JVM language, but
>   this build assumes a single directory for all classes from a source
>   set. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed
>   in Gradle 5.0.

So I believe I need to get rid of this warning before I can update to v5. Problem is I'm not really sure what it's asking me to do. How do I cahnge the build so that it doesn't assume a single directroy for all classes from a source set?

I tried adding the below to the build.gradle but I'm still getting the warning:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        // Compiled Java classes should use this directory
        java.outputDir = new File(buildDir, "classes/java/main")
    }
}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44578302/splitting-all-output-directories-in-gradle

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add anything to the build script.You just need to organize your project [*like this*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:separate_language_source_files):

```
├── build.gradle
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── HelloWorld.java
        └── kotlin
            └── Utils.kt
```

Comment: I've had a look at the module it's moaning about which is the backend and the struture is already setup like that:
backend> src>main>java

Answer (score 0):

That deprecation message is shown when you use `sourceSet.output.classesDir`, which returns a `File`.

This has been replaced in Gradle 4.x, and removed in Gradle 5.x, by `sourceSet.output.classesDirs` (note the `s` at the end) which returns a `FileCollection`.

So you need to figure out where you use that in your buildscript and if not which plugin does. Note that the new method is already available in Gradle 4.x and so you should be able to upgrade your code or plugin version to make the deprecation message go away.

Good hunting!